# What does (foo) in function(args){ ... }(foo) mean?

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with Javascript objects.

What does `(foo)` in `function(args){ ... }(foo)` mean?

Comment: The `args` you want to pass to the `anonymous()` function ! Basically you are invoking the anonymous function with the argument `foo` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a function then right after that you call it. you could do it in 2 steps :

```
function f(args){}

f(foo);
```

Single step and anonymous :

```
(function(args){})(foo);
```

Comment: @jgroenen yep :) thx, we can also see this notation in jquery and modules

Comment: BTW: I think the equivalent would be var f = function(args){}; f(foo);, because anonymous functions are dynamically declared at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

When you see a `function (args) { }` followed by brackets `(foo)`, it is an [immediately invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (IIFE - pronounced 'iffy').

```
function (args) { } (foo);
```

is basically the same as

```
var foofun = function (args) { };
foofun(foo);
```

or

```
function foofun(args) { }
foofun(foo);
```

the expression is just also anonymous, because the function isn't stored into a var and has no name.
So the `foo` is just the parameter for the `args` argument.

Answer (score 1):

this is an example for an `immediately invoced function expression`  (IIFE).
After your anonymous function is declared, it is immediately invoced by calling it with the parameter `foo`.

`foo` is probably just an example for any object that you may pass as a parameter to your function declaration which is about to be called right away.

Answer (score 1):

the function is anonymous (does not have a name), and you call that function with the argument foo

Answer (score 0):

Your statement can be rewritten to:

```
function xy(args) {
   //code here
}

xy(foo);
```

So basically you are just directly calling the function after it's definition and passing a variable `foo` as argument.